# Couldn't send email using smtp.zoho.com in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to send mail using Laravel. Here's my mail configuration in .env.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.zoho.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=booking@bholebabatravels.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xyzh
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

In my controller method:

```
Mail::send('Email.test', ['first_name' => $first_name, 'last_name' => $second_name, 'email' => $request->email, 'msg' => $msg, 'country' => $country, 'street' => $street_address], function ($message){
    $message->to('john.doe@example.com')->subject('Booking Online!');
});
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.zoho.com [A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. #10060]

I googled the problem but all I get is setting proper configuration and that's all. Configuration seems okay. What could be wrong?

Comment: Well, can you connect to `smtp.zoho.com:465`?  If your host is linux, running `telnet smtp.zoho.com 465` is a good way to test connectivity to a specific host/port.

Comment: Try `MAIL_PORT=587` and `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=TLS`

Answer (score 2):

Laravel out of the box sets `hello@example.com` as sender address. If you don't change this value, It is very likely that your email service provider will not let your email go through. 
You can change this in `config/mail.php`

```
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Also one should make sure that MAIL_HOST should be proper. in my case, the Zoho account was in the Indian region so I need to use smtp.zoho.in instead of smtp.zoho.com